# Where is the curvature minimal?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curvature

Where is the curvature minimal?

Now I have found where the curvature is maximum. How ever I don't know how to solve for the minimum.

$$\vec{r}(t)=2\cos(t)\vec{i}+3\sin(t)\vec{j}$$

I used the equation to solve for kappa.

$$\kappa (t)=|\vec{r'(t)} \times \vec{r''}(t)  |/|\vec{r'}(t)|^{3}$$

Can anyone give me some input? Thanks

Comment: Here $r$ describes an ellipse. So it would be easier to go to Cartesian and just pick the corners. Sharper corner is for smaller radius and larger curvature.

Comment: How did you find the maximum curvature?  By setting $\kappa'(t)=0$ and solving for $t$?  The minimum should also come out of that.  Otherwise the minimum is "endpoint-critical" which I strongly doubt is the case.

Comment: @ Doc yes I found k'(t)=0 and solved for t. How would you suggest find where the curvature is minimum?

Comment: Same way. The equation $\kappa(t) = 0$ must have other solutions that you have overlooked, and one of them (at least) corresponds to a minimum. As the comment above said, the curve is an ellipse, and this should help you identify the $t$ value corresponding to minimum curvature.